# CellValueChanged on programmatically added DataGridView's

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem with CellValueChanged on programmatically added DataGridView's here is how I add DataGridView's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
    tabControl_Rozliczenie.TabPages.Add("Id " + lista[i]);
    var dataGridView = new DataGridView()
    {
        Name = "dataGridView_" + lista[i],
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    dataGridView.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_ety_CellValueChanged);
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    tabControl_Rozliczenie.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(dataGridView);
    dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);
}
```

It works correct but on the event which I'm adding in this part code i had some problem with implementing the CellValueChanged

Here is code:

```
var index = dataGridView_Id1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

dataTable.Rows[index][łącznie] = (int)dataTable.Rows[index][columnNumber] + (int)dataTable.Rows[index][ilość];

linaZPodsumowaniem();

int ubytki = (int)dataTable.Rows[index][columnNumber];
int łącznaIlość = (int)dataTable.Rows[inde][łącznie];

double ubytkiDouble = Convert.ToDouble(ubytki);
double łącznaIlośćDouble = Convert.ToDouble(łącznaIlość);

double wartośćWProc = ((100f * ubytkiDouble) / łącznaIlośćDouble);

dataTable.Rows[indexWiersza][wartośćProc] = Math.Round(wartośćWProc,2) + "%";
```

The problem is with

```
  var index = dataGridView_Id1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

It works on dataGridView1.
The problem is I kinda don't know how can I do it on DataGridView in active TabControl.Page.
I know I should checking which TabControl Page is active and then looking for dataGridView on this Page.
Can someone help me accomplish this?

Comment: `var dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;`

Comment: You cannot access in run-time created `DataGridView` by name given in run-rime. As you did in your code `Name = "dataGridView_" + lista[i],`. Use @IvanStoev solution for getting right instance of `DataGridView` in the eventhandler

Comment: Ugh, it was so easy ... Thanks for help, it works :) Since it is in comment I can't accept this as an answer :(